# Model class in View file is difference with model in controller, MVC C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Something odd occur in my website (MVC, C#)
I'm using MVC5 and async actions
Whenever my website is under pressure, e.g: 10 request per second, my model data in View file is not the same with filled model in controller,
I'm dead sure about it,
I tested in local DEBUG mode, model class in View file was difference with filled model class in controller,
I created a Windows Application with tons of async call on my local website in VS2013, so I could test it locally.
Is it occurred for you sometime, if so How to resolve it?

Comment: If you are going to down vote a post have the courage to state why! Smh

Comment: @MarkKram People are not required to state a reason for their downvote. In most cases, writing a comment would take way too much time, especially since posting guidelines are found in the help center of the site. It has nothing to do with 'courage'.

Comment: Try to explain your problem better way or provide some example

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted but it would be really helpful if you provide more detail like what are you doing, something about Model/View/Controller of yours. Does this happens only when there are lot of users or it happens randomly? What do you suspect? Share some insight otherwise no one will be able to understand the problem and won't be able to offer much help. I think this might be the reason of downvote.

Comment: Oh I was under the impression that SO was a community that was created to help others but I guess it is just a place where where some people can feel superior. Now I got it. Smh